# PHP nested foreach not iterating parent varaibles

Tags: php, foreach

New to PHP and trying to create a nestled list, might be doing it sloppy way, but got specific structure in mind. I'm trying to check if the list structure matches the database values.

Problem: Cant seem to iterate the 'buildValue' and 'floorValue' varaibles (created in foreach1 & 2) inside the 3rd foreach loop (the one which references the database). Also tried while loop with same result.

Is there an alternative way of achieving this, or am I doing something wrong/stupid?

```
$htmlArray = array();
$buildingArray = array();

$buildingArray["0"] = array("4","3","2","1","0","01","02");
$buildingArray["1"] = array("4","3","2","1","0","01","02");
$buildingArray["2"] = array("4","3","2","1","0","01","02");

    foreach ($buildingArray as $bkey => $building) 
    {
        switch ($bkey) 
        {
            case "0":
                $htmlArray[0]['building'] = "Biology";
            break;
            case "1":
                $htmlArray[1]['building'] = "Chemistry";
            break;
            case "2":
                $htmlArray[2]['building'] = "Environmental";
            break;
        }

        $buildVal = $bkey;

        foreach ($building as $fkey => $floor) 
        {
            $floorVal = $floor;

            $prepend ='Floor ';
            $title = $prepend.$floor;
            $htmlArray[$fkey]['floor'] = $title;

            // Iterate over the items results 

           //NO PROBLEM: These values (reference foreach1 & foreach2) output correct result!
            echo("build=".$buildVal." ");
            echo("floor=".$floorVal." ");

            $roomArray= array();
            $roomArray = $rooms -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            foreach ($roomArray as $row) 
            {
                //PROBLEM: These values (reference foreach1 & foreach2) do not iterate inside foreach 3, only output 1st building and floor!

                echo("build=".$buildVal." ");
                echo("floor=".$floorVal." ");

                //echo any results matching building and floor
                if($row["building"] == $buildVal+3 && $row["floor"] == $floorVal)
                {
                    // echo($row["room");

                }

            }

        }


    }
```

NO PROBLEM OUTPUT: 
build=0 floor=4 build=0 floor=3 build=0 floor=2 build=0 floor=1 build=0 floor=0 build=0 floor=01 build=0 floor=02 build=1 floor=4 build=1 floor=3 build=1 floor=2 build=1 floor=1 build=1 floor=0 build=1 floor=01 build=1 floor=02 build=2 floor=4 build=2 floor=3 build=2 floor=2 build=2 floor=1 build=2 floor=0 build=2 floor=01 build=2 floor=02

PROBLEM OUTPUT:
build=0 floor=4 build=0 floor=4 build=0 floor=4 build=0 floor=4 build=0 floor=4 build=0 floor=4 build=0 floor=4 build=0 floor=4

$RoomArray Output (seems correct except empty arrays at the end):
Array ( [0] => Array ( [room_id] => 1 [room] => 112 [floor] => 1 [building] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [room_id] => 2 [room] => 111 [floor] => 1 [building] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [room_id] => 3 [room] => 116 [floor] => 1 [building] => 4 ) [3] => Array ( [room_id] => 4 [room] => 115 [floor] => 1 [building] => 4 ) [4] => Array ( [room_id] => 5 [room] => 114 [floor] => 1 [building] => 4 ) [5] => Array ( [room_id] => 6 [room] => 113 [floor] => 1 [building] => 4 ) [6] => Array ( [room_id] => 7 [room] => 110 [floor] => 1 [building] => 5 ) [7] => Array ( [room_id] => 8 [room] => 109 [floor] => 1 [building] => 5 ) ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )

Perhaps I should maybe rephrase the question....the above is from my DB  (although the data will be much larger) , except with 3 buildings and 6 floors and I need a nestled list like:

```
 -Building1
   -Floor1
     -Room121
 -Building2
   -Floor1
   -Floor2
     -Room221
```

etc

Comment: I believe pdo fetchAll outputs it as key=>val; do a var_dump on roomArray.

Comment: Where do you set `$building` and `$rooms`? Once you fetch all the rows from `$rooms` in the first iteration, you can't call `$fetchAll` again unless you rewind it. But it will return the same thing each time, so why do you need to do that inside the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Your question talks about `$buildValue` and `$floorValue`, but there are no such variables in the code. Did you mean `$buildVal` and `$floorVal`?

Comment: $roomArray outputs as expected....the problem seems to be with the foreach varaibles. Yeah $buildVal and $floorVal

Comment: $building and $floors and created from $buildingArray values in foreach1 & 2. The $rooms are pdo result from query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see some issue with indexing $htmlArray variable, but I am not sure what You are doing after $roomArray comes into scene. 
Take a look at code below, maybe it helps. If not - tell exactly what is wrong with $roomArray loop, and what is $roomArray.

**EDIT** I updated my answer, check if this gives You needed output.

```
    $buildingArray["0"] = array("4","3","2","1","0","01","02");
    $buildingArray["1"] = array("4","3","2","1","0","01","02");
    $buildingArray["2"] = array("4","3","2","1","0","01","02");
    # Added simple dictionary
    $btype = array("Biology","Chemistry","Environmental");
    # Prefetch all rooms.
    $roomArray= array();
    $roomArray = $rooms -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    #
    foreach ($buildingArray as $bkey => $building) 
    {
        # This is much nicer than case...
        $htmlArray[$bkey]['building'] = $btype[$bkey];

        foreach ($building as $fkey => $floor) 
        {
            # Two things here - first, user sprintf instead of '.'.
            # Second - You got keys owerwritten with using $fkey as the first key.
            $htmlArray[$bkey]['floor'][$fkey]['title'] = sprintf('Floor %s',$floor);
            foreach ($roomArray as $room) 
            {
                if($room['building']==($bkey+3) and $room['floor']==$fkey)
                {
                    $htmlArray[$bkey]['floor'][$fkey]['rooms'][$room['room_id']] = $room['room'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($htmlArray);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Inisde the if statement: I'm trying to use the $buildVal and $floorVal as a reference to the location in the loops and checking if the database values ($room['building'], $room['floor'] match the values and input the correct data into the correct section. Problem is the $buildVal and $floorVal do not iterate once inisde the foreach($roomArray). I will be adding more echos inside each of the foreach's to provide a nestled list.

Comment: Thanks for improvement over my sloppy prepend :)

Comment: Can You please show what $roomArray looks like? Privide output from print_r($roomArray) ?

Comment: Thanks this edit works perfectly, i think the lack of prefetch caused the issues, can now use if statement! the optimizations of my shady code is a bonus :)